# Block Bootstrap Estimation in Java - Part 3

Tags: java, statistics

This is an extension of [Block Bootstrap Estimation in Java - Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239689/block-bootstrap-estimation-in-java-part-2). The text file text.txt can be found at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vLBoNmFyh4alDZt1eoJpavuEwWlPZSKX (please download the file directly should you wish to test it; there are some odd things about it that you will not pick up through even Notepad). **This is a small 10 x 10 dataset with `maxBlockSize = 10`, but this needs to scale up to twenty 5000 x 3000 datasets with `maxBlockSize = 3000`, just to get an idea of scale.**

If helpful, I have 6 cores available with 64GB of RAM, as well as two GPUs that I have no idea how to use (Intel UHD Graphics 630, NVIDIA Quadro P620). I'll be looking over how to use these in the next few days if I have to, and have also considered re-learning Amazon Web Services.

What is clear to me now is that `mbbVariance` is slowing this program down. Considering how much I need to scale this up, note that `mbbVariance` and `nbbVariance` would have to run for each of the 5,000 rows as arguments (`x` being a row), and have to be iterated (`0` to `x.length - L + 1` for `mbbVariance`, and `0` to `x.length / L` for `nbbVariance`) proportionally to 5,000 times since `maxBlockSize = 5000` implies that values 1, 2, ..., 5000 will be passed as `L` to the `mbbVariance` and `nbbVariance` functions.

While the code below does work, when I ran it for a single 5000 x 3000 data set with `maxBlockSize = 3000`, I ended up shutting it down after about 10 hours. The `nbbThread` finished in 18 minutes, judging by the outputted `NBB_test.txt`. Given how much of `MBB_test.txt` was populated, through linear interpolation, I estimated that `mbbThread` would take about 28 hours total (so 18 hours after I had shut the process down). This is too long, given that I have 20 files of this size to process.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;

public class BlockBootstrapTestParallel {

    // Sum of a subarray, based on B(x, i, L) -- i is one-indexing
    public static double sum(double[] x, int i, int L) {
        return Arrays.stream(x).skip(i - 1).limit(L).sum();
    }

    // Mean of a subarray, based on B(x, i, L) -- i is one-indexing
    public static double mean(double[] x, int i, int L) {
        return Arrays.stream(x).skip(i - 1).limit(L).average().orElse(0);
    }

    // Compute MBB mean
    public static double mbbMu(double[] x, int L) {     
        return IntStream.range(0, x.length - L + 1)
                        .mapToDouble(idx -> mean(x, idx + 1, L))
                        .average()
                        .orElse(0);
    }

    // Compute MBB variance
    public static double mbbVariance(double[] x, int L, double alpha) {
        double mu = mbbMu(x, L);
        double lAlph = Math.pow(L, alpha);

        return IntStream.range(0, x.length - L + 1)
                        .parallel()
                        .mapToDouble(idx -> (lAlph * Math.pow(mean(x, idx + 1, L) - mu, 2)))
                        .average()
                        .orElse(0);
    }

    // Compute NBB mean
    public static double nbbMu(double[] x, int L) {
        return IntStream.range(0, x.length / L)
                        .mapToDouble(idx -> (mean(x, 1 + ((idx + 1) - 1) * L, L)))
                        .average()
                        .orElse(0);
    }

    // Compute NBB variance
    public static double nbbVariance(double[] x, int L, double alpha) {
        double mu = nbbMu(x, L);
        double varSum = IntStream.range(0, x.length / L)
                                 .parallel()
                                 .mapToDouble(idx -> (Math.pow(mean(x, 1 + ((idx + 1) - 1) * L, L) - mu, 2)))
                                 .average()
                                 .orElse(0);

        return Math.pow((double) L, alpha) * varSum;

    }

    // factorial implementation
    public static double factorial(int x) {
        double[] fact = {1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0, 24.0, 120.0, 720.0, 5040.0, 40320.0, 362880.0, 3628800.0};
        return fact[x];
    }

    // Hermite polynomial
    public static double H(double x, int p) {
        double out = IntStream.range(0, (p / 2) + 1)
                              .parallel()
                              .mapToDouble(idx -> (Math.pow(-1, idx) * Math.pow(x, p - (2 * idx)) / 
                                                    ((factorial(idx) * factorial(p - (2 * idx))) * (1L << idx))))
                              .sum();
        out *= factorial(p);
        return out;
    }

    // Row means
    public static double[] rowMeans(double[][] x, int nrows, int ncols) {
        return IntStream.range(0, nrows)
                        .parallel()
                        .mapToDouble(idx -> (mean(x[idx], 1, ncols)))
                        .toArray();
    }

    public static void duration(long start, long end) {
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (((double)(end - start))/60000) + " minutes");
    }


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException, IOException {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutMBB = new FileOutputStream("MBB_test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutNBB = new FileOutputStream("NBB_test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutMean = new FileOutputStream("means_test.txt");

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileIn);
        PrintWriter outFSMBB = new PrintWriter(fileOutMBB);
        PrintWriter outFSNBB = new PrintWriter(fileOutNBB);
        PrintWriter outFSmean = new PrintWriter(fileOutMean);

        // These variables are taken from the command line, but are inputted here for ease of use.
        int rows = 10;
        int cols = 10;
        int maxBlockSize = 10; // this could potentially be any value <= cols
        int p = 1;
        double alpha = 0.1;
        double[][] timeSeries = new double[rows][cols];

        // read in the file, and perform the H_p(x) transformation
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                timeSeries[i][j] = H(scnr.nextDouble(), p);
            }
            scnr.next(); // skip null terminator
        }

        // row means
        double[] sampleMeans = rowMeans(timeSeries, rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            outFSmean.print(sampleMeans[i] + " ");
        }
        outFSmean.println();
        outFSmean.close();

        final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(3);

        Thread mbbThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                gate.await();
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < maxBlockSize; m++) {
                        outFSMBB.print(mbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha) + " ");
                    }
                outFSMBB.println();
                }           
                outFSMBB.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Thread nbbThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                gate.await();
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < maxBlockSize; m++) {
                        outFSNBB.print(nbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha) + " ");
                    }
                outFSNBB.println();
                }           
                outFSNBB.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // start threads simultaneously
        mbbThread.start();
        nbbThread.start();
        gate.await();

        // wait for threads to die 
        mbbThread.join();
        nbbThread.join();

        duration(start, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```